# How can a VIM user replace a word within and subsequently paste a register?

Tags: vim

I am frequently yanking code blocks and replacing certain words. For example, using Visual Line mode I may yank the below code block:

`def meow
  puts "meow!!"
end`

I find myself repeating a <kbd>p</kbd> and `:3,5s/meow/bark/g` pattern. To change the pasted block to:

`def bark
  puts "bark!"
end`

I want to do this several times with a varying amount of animal sounds (maybe "quack", "moo", "honk", "yeeha"). How can I modify the register dynamically to paste with the changed word?

Comment: It looks like you got a good answer below, but for future reference questions like this are a better fit for the Vi and Vim Stack Exchange: http://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Jordan, I will remember that next time! Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store the variable items inside a list, and pop an item <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd><kbd>=</kbd>`remove(mylist,0)`<kbd>Return</kbd> inside a macro to insert each time a different thing. For example, first yank your block:

```
V3jy
```

Initialize a list with the desired items:

```
:let l=["quack", "moo", "honk", "yeeha"]
```

Then record quickly a macro, each time popping a different item in the list:

```
qaPV']:s/meow/<c-r>=remove(l,0)<cr>/g<cr>'[q
```

Note: `<c-r>` above is <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd> key, as well as `<cr>` is <kbd>Return</kbd> key.

Once you recorded the macro, only 3 items stay in the list, so, doing `3@a` will populate your file like this:

```
def yeeha
  puts "yeeha!!"
end

def honk
  puts "honk!!"
end

def moo
  puts "moo!!"
end

def quack
  puts "quack!!"
end

def meow
  puts "meow!!"
end
```

You can adapt this trick in many ways, for example if you don't want to use lists, but a register (let's say `@e`), you can record a different macro:

```
qaPV']:s/meow/<c-r>e/g<cr>'[q
```

and then use this command before each macro call: `:let @e="something"`

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for